# Counting the number of $(d_v,d_c)$ regular bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coding-theory

I am trying to count the number of $(d_v,d_c)$ regular bipartite graphs. To be specific, let $n,m,d_v,d_c$ be positive integers such that 
$$n\times d_v=m\times d_c.$$
Then, what is the number of bipartite graphs $\mathcal{G}=(L\cup R, E)$, where $L$ is the set of left vertices, $R$ is the set of right vertices with the property that each left vertex has $d_v$ edges incident on it, and each right vertex has $d_c$ edges incident on it, allowing parallel edges(i.e., there can be more than one edge between a pair of vertices)? Can one find a general expression for this?

This problem can be reformulated as a ball and bin problem in the following way: We have a total of $nd_v$ balls, of $n$ colors, with $d_v$ balls of each color. What is the number of ways of putting these balls in $m$ nonidentical bins so that each bin has exactly $d_c$ balls? Let me denote this number $\psi(n,d_v,d_c)$ A quick thought about this gives me the following bounds:
$$
 \frac{(nd_v)!}{\left(d_v! \right)^n(d_c!)^m}\leq\psi(n,d_v,d_c)\leq \frac{(nd_v)!}{\left(d_v! \right)^n}.
$$
Can one do better?

I think there must be some work that has addressed this problem but I have not been able to find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what are "parallel edges"? Does it mean you allow multigraphs?
And are you aware that you are using a nonstandard concept of regular?
In a regular bipartite graph $d_v$ and $d_c$ must be identical.
Finally, do you want to count labeled or unlabeled graphs?

Comment: By parallel edges, I mean that there can be more than one edge between a pair of vertices. I know that this terminology may not be standard in graph theory, but it is often used in coding theory. And I want to count unlabeled graphs.

Comment: Interesting problem. I wrote a computer program that can generate the numbers for small
values of the parameters, and found some known subsequences, e.g.
$G(2,2k,4,k)$ is A001973 and $G(2,3k,6,k)$ is A001977, but even the "diagonal"
$G(k,k,k,k)$ is unknown.

Comment: I had also asked this question on mathoverflow [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151268/counting-the-number-of-d-v-d-c-regular-bipartite-graphs), and have got an answer. It looks like for small $d_v,d_c$ there is a bound on $\psi(n,d_v,d_c)$ that is tight upto a factor of $e^{2/(m+n)}$.